# jQuery: How to combine find and filter on an array of elements?

Tags: jquery, dry

I have an array of elements `myRoots`. I want to find all the elements from the array or descendant of an element in the array that matches a certain selector (let's say that are `div`).

You can look at it as the combination of `myRoots.find('div')` and `myRoots.filter('div')`. And I imagine I could write this as `$.merge(myRoots.find('div'), myRoots.filter('div'))`, but would like to [avoid repeating myself](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) (`myRoots` and the selector are repeated). Is there a better way?

In XPath, this corresponds to the [`descendant-or-self` axis](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath20/#axes), and you'd write this `$myRoots/descendant-or-self::div`.

Comment: You can easily write a plugin that does exactly that, though I would say if you need to do that, then you probably should rethink your markup instead.

Comment: @Ilia, descendant-or-self makes sense in many situations of tree traversal, whether in HTML, XML and probably lots of other trees. XPath had this axis in 1999 for a reason, and it is sorely missing in jQuery.

Comment: I don't really agree that such selection makes sense in the context of HTML, but it is a pretty trivial plugin to write, if you really want it.

Answer (score -1):

**Edit**

Try using:
     myRoots.find("div").andSelf().filter("div");

---

You could do:

```
myRoots.find("div").andSelf();
```

Comment: This doesn't to it: it will add to the result all the elements in `myRoots`, whether they are divs or not.